# Integration of smart-tabs-mode and scala-mode2

Tags: scala, emacs

Has anyone integrated smart-tabs-mode and scala-mode2 before?  I'm trying to figure out what to add to smart-tabs-insinuate-alist to support scala - does anyone know?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work. Any info would be helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not use smart-tabs or scala-mode so my answer may not be complete. According to smart-tabs mode's [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs#toc5) page. You can add support for additional languages using `smart-tabs-add-language-support` you will need to specify the the following parameters

1) Language name

2) Language mode hook

3) Indent line functions (and indent region function)

4) Offset variable

Looking at `scala-mode2` it appears to provides a language mode hook (`scala-mode-hook`),  indent line function (`scala-indent:indent-line`) and offset variable (`scala-indent:step`) (it apparently does not provide a function to indent a function). Using this info and assuming that I understood smart-tabs manual correctly you can add support for scala-mode2 using the following code

```
(smart-tabs-add-language-support scala scala-mode-hook
                             ((scala-indent:indent-line . scala-indent:step)))
```

Then to activate the support do

```
(smart-tabs-insinuate 'scala)
```

Also smart-tabs has a [github](https://github.com/jcsalomon/smarttabs) repository, you can always report issues if something does not work for you.